# Where is ServletContainer of Jersey located

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I wanted to try some examples on REST Jersey. Jersey servlet needs to be added to web.xml I added the following entry to web.xml

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I just looked up in [jersey-server](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17/jersey-server-1.17.jar) and I don't find ServletContainer SPI class at all. Am I looking at a wrong jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of jersey, starting from `1.10`, `ServletContainter` is in [**jersey-servlet**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet),

In older versions, it is included in [**jersey-bundle**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle).

Answer (score 1):

The `ServletContainer` is present in [Jersey-servlet.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet/1.17.1)

Answer (score 0):

Download the Jersey bundle JAR in the below location and try:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#chapter_deps